# On Windows, mvn jetty:run is fine but mvn jetty:run-war fails

Tags: scala, maven, jetty

I am developing a web app with lift+scala. Everything works on Ubuntu Linux. When I switch to Windows (the production environment), mvn jetty:run still works, but mvn jetty:run-war doesn't work anymore, and unsurprisingly, deploying the WAR to jetty/tomcat doesn't work in this environment either.

Here is the maven pom.xml

http://pastebin.com/ekk57Z2f

Here is the error message when I run mvn jetty:run-war or deploying it to jetty/tomcat server in production

http://pastebin.com/0x0rNpRy

System environment variable CLASSPATH is empty.

What mvn jetty:run does specifically, that mvn jetty:run-war doesn't do? I suspect it is some classpath / classloader conflict problem.

One more thing: It doesn't work either when I deploy the WAR to tomcat on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependency lift.json points to a different version of Lift, which is built upon a different major version of Scala. Therefore, when lift.json is invoked on environments without the required (lower) version of Scala installed, ClassDefNotFound error would occur.